# WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1/app/anyKey?protocol=7&client=js&version=6.0.3&flash=false' failed. how to fix this laravel websocket error

Tags: php, npm, websocket, node-modules, laravel-7

**broadcasting.php my sample. i don't know how to fix it**
**If you know the answer please help me**

```
'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'encrypted' => false,   
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => 6001,
            'scheme' => 'http',
        ],
    ],
```

[Error Photo click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS72l.jpg)

Comment: I think the issue is npm node modules, I found it. but the solution is not found for that